# Image binding works in Image not in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, image, data-binding, itemscontrol

I am a bit baffled here. I have a `List<BitmapImage>` in a Viewmodel that is populating. I am trying to display the list on the view with an ItemsControl, but the Images don't show up. Oddly, I can access the same collection and get an image to display if I am using an Image tag.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" MinHeight="80">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" MinWidth="80" MinHeight="80" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Path=Images[0]}" MinHeight="80" MaxHeight="200" />
```

Note that they both point to `Images`. The Image shows up, the ItemsControl stays empty. What is going on?

Comment: Code looks right to me, how are you setting the `Images` property? Are you modifying it?

Comment: Its getting populated with images from the web. I'm pretty sure its working though since the `Image` tag is displaying the first Image.

Comment: Is the your List populated before the binding occurs or after? Since you aren't using an ObservableCollection, if it's bound first and then populated, the ItemsControl won't see the items.

Comment: Neither then would the Image. The Viewmodel uses INotifyPropertyChanged once population is finished.

Comment: Quote: Neither then would the Image...
Actually, INotifyPropertyChanged would work for the image but not for the List.

Comment: Really? I Swear I have used INotifyPropertyChanged with a list property before. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll solve this by using an ObservableCollection as opposed to a List. The ItemsControl isn't going to rebind on the change notification of a List. You won't have to worry about explicitly calling the change notification for the List either if you use an ObservableCollection.

I was able to replicate your scenario and simply using an ObservableCollection solves the issue. As to why: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Specifically, see this quote in the Remarks section:

> For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source, your bound type should either: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred). Provide a change event for each property of the bound type. Do not do both.

Comment: You are correct, but I am curious as to why Lists wont update after INotifyPropertyChanged is called on them.

Comment: @Tyrsius: If you have a *new* list and you use INotifyPropertyChanged, it will update. If you just modify an existing list (including clearing it and repopulating) it won't, because your property still points to the same list.

Comment: @MattBurland Ah, that makes sense. Is there no way to get the list to update its collection then with INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Tyrsius: You could a) Replace it with a new instance of a list, or b) set your property to null and then back to your list. Neither option is really better than using ObservableCollection.